# Расположить изображения равномерно по всему блоку на веб-старнице

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Нужно разместить множество изображений равной высоты и разной ширины так, чтобы они расположились ровно по ширине страницы с равными или почти равными промежутками, как, например, [здесь](https://yandex.by/images/search?text=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0) или [здесь](https://pixabay.com/en/photos/?q=spring&image_type=&cat=&min_width=&min_height=).

Как это лучше сделать, скриптом на сервере, через JavaScript или, может быть, можно через CSS?

Comment: Есть отдельные плагины делающие подобные "плитки", но можно попробовать и на css, используя флексы.